# Unable to run VLC in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, vlc, shared-library

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. After installing VLC so many times still VLC does not open via GUI. It is working from the terminal, but I can not use any other VLC features with it. The error message is shown below:

```
Main libvlc error: cannot load plug-in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt_plugin.so: libqt5Svg.so.5: cannot open shared object
file: no such file or directory.
```

Comment: How did you install VLC ?

Comment: i installed it via terminal and app center both

Answer (score -1):

You can download and install using snap here is command :-

```
sudo snap install vlc
```

you can check this link for more info :- [link](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html)
it worked for me.